# Sending email(outlook as server) in azure databricks notebook in python?

Tags: python, azure, smtp, office365, databricks

I tried to configure using localhost. I ran this in my cmd line.
(python -m smtpd -c DebuggingServer -n localhost:1025)

```
import smtplib, ssl

smtp_server = "localhost"
port = 1025  # For starttls
sender_email = "my outlook email"
password =  input("Type your password and press enter: ")

# Create a secure SSL context
context = ssl.create_default_context()

# Try to log in to server and send email
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
    server.ehlo() # Can be omitted
    server.starttls(context=context) # Secure the connection
    server.ehlo() # Can be omitted
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    print("server connected")
    # TODO: Send email here
except Exception as e:
    # Print any error messages to stdout
    print(e)
finally:
    server.quit()
```

But it is giving  "connection refused" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve `connection refused` error, you can try following ways:

- Firewall might be blocking access to port 1025
- Alternatively, you can try [using port 25](https://www.futurequest.net/forums/archive/index.php/t-22718.html)

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity):

> For Enterprise Dev/Test subscriptions, port 25 is blocked by default. It is possible to have this block removed. To request to have the block removed, go to the Cannot send email (SMTP-Port 25) section of the Diagnose and Solve blade in the Azure Virtual Network resource in the Azure portal and run the diagnostic. This will exempt the qualified enterprise dev/test subscriptions automatically.

You can refer to [Send emails from Azure Databricks](https://kohera.be/azure-cloud/how-to-send-emails-with-an-smtp-server-in-azure-databricks/)